# How do I get the current file, current class, and current method with Python?

Tags: python, filenames

- Name of the file from where code is running
- Name of the class from where code is running
- Name of the method (attribute of the class) where code is running

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here is an example of each:

```
from inspect import stack

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        print __file__
        print self.__class__.__name__
        print stack()[0][3]

f = Foo()
```

Comment: Are you trying to run it from the command line? It obviously isn't defined then; try creating a file with the code and doing python filename - it will work as expected.

Comment: Why not inspect.currentframe ?

Comment: `self.__class__` is not the current class. The current class is `__class__`.

Answer (score 11):

```
import sys

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print __file__
        print self.__class__.__name__
        print sys._getframe().f_code.co_name

a = A()
```

Comment: isn't using of private method outside of module considered a bad practice and against the original purpose of Python sys library? isn't there any better way for this?

Comment: `self.__class__` is not the current class. The current class is `__class__`.

Answer (score 5):

```
self.__class__.__name__  # name of class i'm in
```

for the rest the sys and trace modules

http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html
http://docs.python.org/library/trace.html

Some more info:
https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2001-August/096499.html
and
http://www.dalkescientific.com/writings/diary/archive/2005/04/20/tracing_python_code.html

did you want it for error reporting because the traceback module can handle that:

http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html

Comment: `self.__class__` is not the current class. The current class is `__class__`.

Answer (score 3):

Be *very* careful. Consider:

```
class A:
    pass

B = A
b = B()
```

What is the 'class name' of `b` here? Is it A, or B? Why?

The point is, you shouldn't need to know or care. An object is what it is: its name is very rarely useful.

Comment: The class name is `A` since `b` is an **Instance** of `B` which in turn is a **reference** to `A` which is a **Class**.

Comment: To end users, surely; but extremely useful when debugging -- like for an exception handler or similar to report where it is. You could compose a nice error message to say the same thing, but it would frequently have this information in it anyway, in which case it seems a waste to type it every time. Also, to build (for example) a general logging package, it's immensely useful to be able to provide this automatically. If your argument held, wouldn't it also apply just as well to isinstance(), which surely is important and useful?